# How can I convert my Ask Ubuntu account?

Tags: discussion, email

I'm quitting with Google mail, but I cannot edit my address to my new one (first time I logged in with Google-login).

Just says *"oops, there was an error"*.

Answer (score 6):

If you try now, you should be able to do that. We had some server issues.

To change your choice of logins:

Head to your user page.

Then, click the "my logins" button:

[image]

Click the "Add more logins..." button.
[image]

Then just add a login from the list here:

[image]